# execute to exe. successful by pyinstaller, but the exe. is not work. How can I debug it

Tags: python-3.x

It's work on `Spyder (Anaconda3)` and execute script to exe by `pyinstaller` without any errors, but nothing happens when I double click exe (also try `cx_freeze`, but still not work either).

How can I debug it? Appreciate for your help.

```
import os,shutil

cur_path=os.path.dirname(__file__)
sample_tree=os.walk(cur_path)

for dirname,subdir,files in sample_tree:
    allfiles=[]
    basename=os.path.basename(dirname)

    for file in files:
        ext=file.split('.')[-1]
        if ext=="csv":#讀取.csv to allfiles
            allfiles.append(file)
        elif ext=='log':#讀取.log to allfiles
            allfiles.append(file)

    for file in allfiles:#Copy csv and log of sample_tree to destfolder
        destfile = cur_path
        srcfile=dirname + "/" + file
        shutil.move(srcfile,destfile)
```

p.s. `python 3.6/pyinstaller 3.3/Win 10`

Answer (score 1):

Debugging is s simple enough process.

In cx_Freeze you can find any errors by doing the following:

- Before building ensure your script works correctly.
- When building from a setup script see If any errors or warnings appear while it turns into an application. Do not worry if you get warnings you get these even when the application works correctly just ensure you know about them since they may give you a clue why it is not working.
- When you application has been built it run it from command line.  This final step will show up any errors.

Next you need to configure you setup script accordingly and recompile it and finally run through the process again to see if you have fixed the problem.

For Pyinstaller follow the same process.

In both modules the best debugging method is to run it from command line.

You can check your application by opening a new terminal window where the application is located and running it

For Linux and CMD (Windows):

```
yourappname
```

and for PowerShell:

```
./yourappname
```

Comment: In addition to @Xantium's answer, you can use DebugView application as per "When things go wrong" guide of pyinstaller.

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html